# How to set image for a column of table with TableCell

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I use material-ui to build a table with a column containing image.

My code as below, but the images don't display.

```
<TableBody>
    {data.map(n => (
      <TableRow key={n.id}>
        <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
          {n.first_name}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell>{n.last_name}</TableCell>
        <TableCell><image src={n.avatar}></image></TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    ))}
</TableBody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using [HTML image tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) or material-ui image component? If it is HTML image tag, it should be `<img src={n.avatar} />` not `<image src={n.avatar}></image>`!

Comment: Thanks Avanthika, I used the autocompletion from Visual Code, and didn't aware that is JSX attribute